Pyton/Selenium Code just skip of some elements of code
Good day, guys.
I want it to go to the page that is entered in select_page and scroll it to the end, check if this is the end, then load the image and then go to another page or end if end_page matches the current page and everything in a circle.
When going to the first page, everything works correctly, but when going to the second, it skips the scrolling part and starts downloading or simply clicks on the button that leads to the next page.
Please, help.
Here's the code:
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from io import BytesIO
from time import sleep
from requests import get
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PIL import Image as PilImage

url = 'https://honey-manga.com.ua'

def download_images(name_manga, select_page, end_page):
    # Create a PDF file
    pdf_file = f'{name_manga}.pdf'
    c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_file, pagesize=letter)
    # Initialize the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')  # Activate headless mode
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Navigate to the webpage
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Find and click the search button
    button_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex items-center gap-x-4']"))
    )
    button_search = button_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div/button")
    button_search.click()
    
    # Enter the manga name into the search input field
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "input"))
    )
    search.send_keys(name_manga)
    
    # Click on the search result
    button_res = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='flex gap-x-4']"))
    )
    button_res.click()
    
    # Click on the read button
    button_read = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mt-6 md:flex md:items-center max-md:grid max-md:grid-cols-12 gap-x-2']"))
    )
    button_read = button_read.find_element(By.XPATH, "./button[2]")
    button_read.click()
    
    # Navigate to the selected page if specified
    if select_page != '':
        while True:
            list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex items-center justify-center md:gap-x-2']"))
            )
            page = list.find_element(By.XPATH, "./button")
            page = str(page.text)
            if page:
                page = page[page.index("-"):]
                page = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, page)))
                print(page)
            if page == int(select_page):
                print("Go")
                break
            else:
                try:
                    button = list.find_element(By.XPATH, "./a[2]")
                    button.click()
                except Exception:
                    # If the "Next" button is not found, exit the loop
                    break
    
    # Main loop to scroll through and capture images
    while True:
        step = 1000  # Set the desired scroll step size
        current_scroll_position = 0
        
        # Scroll through the page until reaching the bottom
        while True:
            page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
            # Scroll the page
            for i in range(current_scroll_position, page_height, step):
                driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {i});")
                sleep(0.1)
                current_scroll_position = i
            # Check if the entire page has been scrolled
            new_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
            if new_page_height == page_height:
                break
        
        sleep(5)  # Wait for a few seconds for the page to load completely
        
        # Find all images on the page
        images = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='md:container']"))
        )
        images = images.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//img")
        
        # Download and add images to the PDF
        for img in images:
            img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
            if img_url:
                try:
                    response = get(img_url)
                    img_data = BytesIO(response.content)
                    pil_image = PilImage.open(img_data)
                    img_width, img_height = pil_image.size
                    pdf_width, pdf_height = img_width, img_height  # Set PDF page size based on image size
                    c.setPageSize((pdf_width, pdf_height))  # Set the PDF page size
                    c.drawImage(ImageReader(img_data), 0, 0, pdf_width, pdf_height)  # Add image to PDF
                    c.showPage()  # Add a new page to the PDF
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error adding image to PDF: {e}")
        
        # Scroll back to the top of the page
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
        
        # Check if the current page matches the end_page
        list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex items-center justify-center md:gap-x-2']"))
        )
        page = list.find_element(By.XPATH, "./button")
        page = page.text
        page = page[page.index("-"):]
        page = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, page)))
        print(page)
        if page == int(end_page):
            print("Session ended page")
            break
        
        # Click on the next page button
        list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex items-center justify-center md:gap-x-2']"))
        )
        sleep(5)
        button = list.find_element(By.XPATH, "./a[2]")
        button.click()
    
    # Save the PDF file
    c.save()
    
    # Quit the webdriver
    driver.quit()



This cannot be the whole code.  The download_images() function is defined but never called.

The function is launched in another code with an interface and all data passes correctly
